# Writing XML based on dynamically generated data

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmlwriter

I will be writing an XML file via C# where the data for the elements is dynamic. So typically, I'll have this structure (simplified for the question):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Output xmlns="http://xxxx/xxx.xsd">
  <AccountHolder>
    <Name></Name>
    <Address1></Address1>
    <City></City>
    <State></State>
    <ZipCode></ZipCode>
  </AccountHolder>
  <Visits>
    <VisitDate></VisitDate>
    <Copay></Copay>
    <CoInsurance></CoInsurance>    
  </Visits>
  <PatientDetails>
    <AcctNo></AcctNo>
    <PatientName></PatientName>
    <Medicare></Medicare>
    <VisitDetails>
      <VDate></VDate>      
      <Amount></Amount>
      <NonCoveredAmount></NonCoveredAmount>
    </VisitDetails>   
  </PatientDetails>
</Output>
```

Now, while there will always be one "Account Holder" there will be anywhere from 0 to multiple visits. Subsequently, there will be list of 0 or more Patients, and then nested within the patients, there will be 0 or more visit details.

I do not control the structure. I need to take the collected data I receive and create the XML. I'll be receiving data on a single account holder which may have any number of the subsequent elements.

I have classes for AccountHolder, Visit, PatientDetails, and VisitDetails. However, I am unsure as to the best method for building out the XML dynamically as I read the source data? At first, I was thinking on gathering the data in various collections.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Output output = new Output()
            {
                Accountholder = new AccountHolder()
                {
                    Name = "",
                    Address1 = "",
                    City = "",
                    State = "",
                    ZipCode = ""
                },
                Visits = new Visits(),
                PatientDetails = new PatientDetails()
                {
                    AccNo = "",
                    PatientName = "",
                    Medicare = "",
                    VisitDetails = new List<VisitDetails>()
                    {
                        new VisitDetails()
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(string.Empty, "http://xxxx/xxx.xsd");

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Output));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, output);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://xxxx/xxx.xsd")]
    public class Output
    {
        public AccountHolder Accountholder { get; set; }
        public Visits Visits { get; set; }
        public PatientDetails PatientDetails { get; set; }
    }
    public class AccountHolder
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address1 {  get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
    public class Visits
    {
        public DateTime VisitDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Copay { get; set; }
        public decimal CoInsurance { get; set; }
    }
    public class PatientDetails
    {
        public string AccNo { get; set; }
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public string Medicare { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public List<VisitDetails> VisitDetails { get; set; }
    }
    public class VisitDetails
    {
        public DateTime VDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public decimal NonCoveredAmount { get; set; }
    }

 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand this, but I think that would assume I first knew how many elements I'll be creating. From what I gather, Linq requires the XML to be created all at once, so I cannot add to it as I cycle through the data for a given transactiont?

That's why I thought I have to "collect" all the data, say in a series of collections, then loop through each while building the XML? 

I wouldn't' think that creating a file, then reopening and modifying as I go, repeat and rinse, is the correct way to go about this.

I appreciate everyone's help on this very much.

Comment: You need to loop through the data returned by query and then add data to the classes.  Same can be done using Linq.  You have to loop when adding data since linq is a query (read) and you are writing to the xml.  Post sample of database query and I will show you how to add to classes.

Comment: Ok now I follow you, understood. I'll give this a try. Thank you very much.....